# Lambda function is not triggered by S3 put event trigger. There is no cloud watch log for the event either

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I created Lambda function to process csv file when it is uploaded to S3.

My trigger:

```
S3: bucket
arn:aws:s3:::bucket
Details
Event type: ObjectCreatedByPut
Notification name: ~notification name~
Suffix: .csv
```

I have had thousands of files uploaded and processed.

I wanted to process one file again due to some issues with data. So I deleted the file, uploaded the file. I have did that multiple times previously and it worked until recently it wasn't.

My code is from blueprint.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:
        bucket_name = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        path_to_file = record['s3']['object']['key']
```

I checked the Cloud Watch logs under the log group but there is no log created when I put the file. I am not sure what is going on.

I gave full access to CloudWatchLogs just to be sure. Still nothing.

Comment: If you've been able to do this in the past, look for what changed in the deployment.

Comment: Are you sure that the file's suffix is `.csv`? Are you sure that the upload happens via PUT? Typically you should trigger on the broader `s3:ObjectCreated:*` event, imo. PS you don't have to delete the object before uploading the new version.

Comment: @Parsifal All of this is just today.

Comment: @jarmod got it. I'll change the trigger and try it now.

Comment: @jarmod I made sure the file is .csv. I am using aws cli to do a sync with S3 bucket. Not sure which is being created PUT or POST but I changed the event type to ObjectCreated. Still no signs of life.

Comment: I would use the AWS console to check that the S3 event trigger is enabled and correctly-configured. Then I would manually upload a test CSV file to the bucket and then check CloudWatch Logs to ensure that my Lambda function was invoked correctly.

Comment: @jarmod I did not change anything. Now it is working...